# Java - Logging if space key is pressed

Tags: java, logging, key

I want to log if the space key is pressed or not. It should look somehow like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

        if(space is pressed){               //asks if key is pressed
            System.out.println("1");
        }else {
            System.out.println("0");
        }

        try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);                 //5000 milliseconds delay
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Standard java API does not provide any global hook to keyboard. This is to prevent keylogger like exploit. You can only listen to keyboard event send to a Java GUI component you created.

Comment: Implement java.awt.event.KeyListener and listen for events;